# How to combine numpy 3d array shape (326, 25, 16) and 1d array shape (326,)

Tags: python, numpy

how to combine numpy  3d array shape (326, 25, 16) and 1d array shape (326,)
the array shape (326, 25, 16) is input for CNN and array shape (326,) is the labels.

Answer (score 0):

My best guest about what you want to do is copying and resizing your array.

```
# same dimensions as your array
a=np.random.randn(326)
# then you can tile (repeat) your array to have the same shape 
# of your other array to do element-wise operations or something else 
b=np.tile(a.reshape(-1,1,1),(1,25,16))
```

The shape of the variable `b`is now `(326, 25, 16)`.

Comment: Thank you . How can I write this new array to csv file  please .

Comment: `np.savetxt("foo.csv", b, delimiter=",")`